# What is the proper way to wrap this php loop around the javascript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I am mashing together the Google Maps 2 script with a Wordpress loop so there is a CMS platform for the map data.  I have this working fine :

```
var point = new GLatLng(48.5139,-123.150531);
var marker = createMarker(point,"Lime Kiln State Park", 
'<?php $post_id = 182;
$my_post = get_post($post_id);
$mapTitle  = $my_post->post_title;
$mapIMG = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mapImage', true);
$snip = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mapExcerpt', true);
echo "<div class=\"span-12\">";
echo "<div class=\"mapTitle\">";
echo $mapTitle;
echo "</div>";
echo "<img class=\"mapImage\" src=\"";
echo bloginfo('url');
echo "/wp-content/files_mf/";
echo $mapIMG;
echo "\" /> ";
echo "<div class=\"mapContent\">";
echo $snip;
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"moreLink\">";
echo "<a href=\"";
echo $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
echo "\">Find out more &raquo; </a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
?>')
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

However I am hoping to also be able to include the two variables at the start within the php loop so that both of those can also be generated by custom fields.  Can someone please show me that the proper way to write this would be so that all of the data can be pulled in from fields within that post id? So the lat/long and title could also be set from within the post 182 fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you're asking. I think the biggest thing that would help you is looking at your coding conventions. Readability is very important. For example, try not to mix php with output too much. Do the php first, and then further down the page just echo your prepared variables where you need them. It makes things a lot easier to read. Also, single quotes are your friend.

I believe this fixes your problem:

```
<?php
$post_id = 182;
$my_post = get_post($post_id);
$mapTitle  = $my_post->post_title;
$mapIMG = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mapImage', true);
$snip = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mapExcerpt', true);
$permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );

// Is this what you mean??
$lat = $my_post->post_lat;
$long = $my_post->post_long;

$pass_to_function = '
    <div class="span-12">
        <div class="mapTitle">'.$mapTitle.'</div>
        <img class="mapImage" 
            src="'.bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/files_mf/'.$mapIMG.'" />
        <div class="mapContent">'.$snip.'</div>
        <div class="moreLink">
            <a href="'.$permalink.'">Find out more &raquo; </a>
        </div>
    </div>';

?>

var point = new GLatLng(<?php echo $lat.', '.$long; ?>);
var marker = createMarker(point,"<?php echo $mapTitle; ?>", '<?php echo $pass_to_function; ?>')
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: I wouldn't even use the multi-line variable assignment. A heredoc is FAR more readable, especially if you have to start escaping quotes within the assignment statement and/or interpolating variables.

Comment: You may be right. Something about heredoc syntax used to irritate me, but that was when I was very inexperienced. Perhaps I'll try it out again and see if I like it better this time around.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your code however there is something wrong with the syntax. I suspect because I am calling this in the middle of the javaScript, that is why my code is a bit odd with all the echos.. this was the only way i could get it to work.. I will keep monkeying with what you have here and see if I can get anything to work.

Comment: You're right, I left out two single quotes. I've edited my code and added them. Probably wouldn't have happened if I had used heredoc like Mark B said, so I think I'll be using those from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all `echo`s and make it this way:

```
$snip = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mapExcerpt', true); 
?>
<div class="span-12"> 
<div class="mapTitle">
<?=$mapTitle?>
</div>
...etc
```

Comment: i dont understand how that would work as I am going to be pulling from about 20 different post ids but the same fields, 'mapExcerpt' etc.. are going to be pulled in for each one.  Dont I have to have them all encased in a loop so that the correct fields are pulled for that id?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this as a comment, but there's no coding formating there, so...

"... I am going to be pulling from about 20 different post IDs..."

How are these post IDs retrieved? From a database? What data is being pulled? I'm guessing the latitude/longitude, the marker name, and the marker's ID, right? If that's the case, then something like this would work:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, lat, long, name FROM table..."; // whatever it would be
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetchrow_array($res)) {
    $title = get_title($row['id']);
    $img = get_Post_Meta($row['id']);
    // and populate more variables for whatever data you need

    // start a heredoc
    echo <<<EOF
var point = new GLatLng({$row['lat']},{$row['long']});
var marker = createMarker(point,"{$row['name']}", '
    <div class="this">
       <div class="that">
           {$title}    <img src="{$img}" />
       </div>
    </div>
';

EOF;
    } // end of while loop
```

Just remember to sanitize any text you're inserting as Javascript code. If (say) the marker's name contains the same type of quotes you're inserting it inside of, it will cause a javascript syntax error, so be sure to escape the appropriate quotes for whatever you're inserting the variable into.

Comment: I think maybe my question was not clear enough about what I am trying to accomplish.  I am using the Wordpress platform and trying to pull custom fields written from the post editor from the database and plug them in to the javascript used to power a google map.  I am a bit lost from your response but thanks, I will see what I can do with it and hopefully learn a thing or two!